# Netinstall version of elementary OS freya?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

Just wondering if there is a netinstall version of elementary OS that can fit on a CD-R? If so, where can I download the ISO?

Comment: [elementary.io](http://www.elementary.io) gives me no such alternative, so there is no official version. But what's the problem with DVDs or USB sticks?

Comment: @bigbang nothing wrong with dvds or usbs except I can't boot from a USB on my mac hardware, and I didn't have a DVD available.